# JAVA vs Python Socket defaults

Tags: java, sockets, python-2.7

I'm pretty sure that my root problem is the antivirus app managed by our network, but my a basic socket client I wrote in Python that worked up until a short time ago is now giving me "socket error 10013". I also have the [SocketTest](http://sockettest.sourceforge.net)  app in JAVA. SocketTest works, but I have been unsuccessful in getting Python to connect. 
The WIN 7 PC has two network cards, not bridged. I have switched the firewall on and off. If I disable the connection to the corporate LAN then the Python client is happy. Just to reiterate, this configuration worked for several months.
I cannot find the difference. Here is the sample code:

Python

```
MY_IP = '192.168.100.2'
MY_PORT = 62828
ROBOT_IP = "192.168.100.10"
ROBOT_SOCK = 29999

robotSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
robotSocket.bind((MY_IP, MY_PORT)) # Tried without binding
robotSocket.connect((ROBOT_IP, ROBOT_SOCK))
```

Result "socket error 10013"

JAVA:

```
socket = new Socket(ROBOT_IP, ROBOT_SOCK);
is = socket.getInputStream();
in = new BufferedInputStream(is);
while (!desonnected)
{
    try
{
    String got = readInputStream(in); // in.readLine();
```

This works fine, but I cannot find the difference to adjust my Python code. I'm sure it is the OfficeScan, but....

**Edit**

I ran WireShark as suggested. With both network cards enabled the Python connection request is not sent.
After disabling the corporate LAN, I compared the Connection requests between the JAVA client and the Python client and they contained the same data except for the local port of course.

Comment: Most firewall tools can allow one program but disallow another to access the network. It is most likely such as setting if your code used to work.

Comment: Wireshark can rescue you. Observe request, response. You have to do that. There is no alternative. Do it now or do it later. Wireshark [or any similar tool :|]

Comment: Might be worth checking the IP address of the machine is indeed equal to `MY_IP`

Comment: So you got your code working when you're only using 1 NIC?

Comment: Yes, when disabling the corporate NIC the code again works fine.
I gave up fiddling with it and am just finishing the re-write in JAVA.

Comment: I should have come back and updated this, but I was so grateful to just get it working.
It was an unannounced corporate firewall policy change.
It took a couple of months for out IT dept to acknowledge the change and provide a rule exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently struggled a lot with socket binding and multiple NICs on Windows 7.

I'm normally a unix guy, but I had to do some C#.Net for a friend as a favor..

MY problem was that I couldn't bind a socket to a specific port and ip on the client side. The solution was to increase the "binding priority" of the NIC I wanted to bind to. I don't know much about Windows, so I can't really elaborate more. Read this article for some info, it helped me: [Network adapter card priority binding order in windows 7](http://techrena.net/view-change-network-adapter-card-priority-binding-order-windows-7/)

Not sure if you're experiencing the same problem, as a socket error 10013 seems to be permission related. Google gives me this: [dealing with socket error 10013](http://wiki-errors.com/dealing-with-socket-error-10013/)